# Finding a random sentence in HTML with python regex

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to write a small function for another script that pulls the generated text from "http://subfusion.net/cgi-bin/quote.pl?quote=humorists&number=1"
Essentially, I need it to pull whatever sentence is between < br> tags.

I've been trying my darndest using regular expressions, but I never really could get the hang of those.
All of the searching I did turned up things for pulling either specific sentences, or single words.
This however needs to pull whatever arbitrary string is between < br> tags.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

*Best I could come up with:*

```
html = urlopen("http://subfusion.net/cgi-bin/quote.pl?quote=humorists&number=1").read()
output = re.findall('\<br>.*\<br>', html)
```

EDIT: Ended up going with a different approach all together, simply splitting the HTML in a list seperated by < br> and pulling [3], made for cleaner code and less string operations. Keeping this question up for future reference and other people with similar questions.

Comment: Google "beautiful soup" and you will be enlightened...

Comment: Beautiful soup is now my new favourite import, thank you @Floris

Comment: I am glad to hear it. It really is spectacularly good, isn't it. But what a crazy name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is uh, 7 years later, but for future reference:

Use the beautifulsoup library for these kind of purposes, as suggested by Floris in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `DOTALL` flag as there are newlines in the expression that you need to match.  I would use

```
re.findall('<br>(.*?)<br>', html, re.S)
```

However will return multiple results as there are a bunch of `<br><br>` on that page.  You may want to use the more specific:

```
re.findall('<hr><br>(.*?)<br><hr>', html, re.S)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re
html = urlopen("http://subfusion.net/cgi-bin/quote.pl?quote=humorists&number=1").read()
output = re.findall('<body>.*?>\n*([^<]{5,})<.*?</body>', html, re.S)

if (len(output) > 0):
    print(output)
    output = re.sub('\n', ' ', output[0])
    output = re.sub('\t', '', output)
    print(output)
```

**Terminal**

```
imac2011:Desktop allendar$ python test.py 
['A black cat crossing your path signifies that the animal is going somewhere.\n\t\t-- Groucho Marx\n\n']

A black cat crossing your path signifies that the animal is going somewhere. -- Groucho Marx
```

You could also strip of the final `\n`'s and replace all those inside the text (on longer quotes) with `<br />` if you are displaying it in HTML again, so you would maintain the original line breaks visually.

Answer (score 0):

All jokes of that page have the same model, no ambigous things, you can use this

```
output = re.findall('(?<=<br>\s)[^<]+(?=\s{2}<br)', html)
```

No need to use the dotall flag cause there's no dot.